# Why do I get cast error with INET configurator

Tags: casting, omnet++, inet

The following error appears during initializing my network:

> <!> check_and_cast(): Cannot cast (inet::Ipv4FlatNetworkConfigurator*)GigabitNetwork.configurator to type 'inet::Ipv4NetworkConfigurator *' -- in module (inet::Ipv4NodeConfigurator) GigabitNetwork.standardHost[0].ipv4.configurator (id=421), during network initialization

I have been trying to solve it for a while, but without success.

Here is my network:

```
Network GigabitNetwork
{
    parameters:
        int numHosts;
        @display("bgb=449,342");
    types:
        channel Ether1000m extends DatarateChannel
        {
            datarate = 1000Mbps;
            delay = 0.1s;
        }
submodules:
    CentralSwitch: EtherSwitch {
        @display("p=189,139");
    }
    Switch1: EtherSwitch {
        @display("p=149,198");
    }
    Switch2: EtherSwitch {
        @display("p=271,198");
    }
    Switch3: EtherSwitch {
        @display("p=258,76");
    }
    Switch4: EtherSwitch {
        @display("p=143,94");
    }
    standardHost[numHosts]: StandardHost {
        @display("p=334,38");
    }
    standardHost1[numHosts]: StandardHost {
        @display("p=342,205");
    }
    standardHost2[numHosts]: StandardHost {
        @display("p=57,256");
    }
    standardHost3[numHosts]: StandardHost {
        @display("p=42,38");
    }
    Server: StandardHost {
        @display("p=42,146;i=device/server");
    }
    configurator: Ipv4FlatNetworkConfigurator {
        @display("p=201,293");
    }
connections:
    CentralSwitch.ethg++ <--> Ether1000m <--> Server.ethg++;
    CentralSwitch.ethg++ <--> Ether1000m <--> Switch4.ethg++;
    CentralSwitch.ethg++ <--> Ether1000m <--> Switch3.ethg++;
    CentralSwitch.ethg++ <--> Ether1000m <--> Switch2.ethg++;
    CentralSwitch.ethg++ <--> Ether1000m <--> Switch1.ethg++;
    for i=0..numHosts-1 {
        standardHost1[i].ethg++ <--> Ether1000m <--> Switch2.ethg++;
        standardHost2[i].ethg++ <--> Ether1000m <--> Switch1.ethg++;
        standardHost[i].ethg++ <--> Ether1000m <--> Switch3.ethg++;
        standardHost3[i].ethg++ <--> Ether1000m <--> Switch4.ethg++;
    }
}
```

And my INI file:

```
[General]
network = GigabitNetwork

sim-time-limit = 120s

**.numHosts = 5

*.*.numApps = 1

**.channel.throughput.statistic-recording = true
**.channel.throughput.result-recording-modes = all
**.*.vector-recording = true 
**.*.vector-recording-intervals= 0..3600

[Config Udp]
*.standardHost[*].app[0].typename = "UdpVideoStreamClient"
*.standardHost[*].app[0].serverAddress = "Server"
*.standardHost[*].app[0].serverPort = 1000
*.standardHost[*].app[0].startTime = uniform(0s, 0.1s)

*.standardHost1[*].app[0].typename = "UdpVideoStreamClient"
*.standardHost1[*].app[0].serverAddress = "Server"
*.standardHost1[*].app[0].serverPort = 1000
*.standardHost1[*].app[0].startTime = uniform(0s, 0.1s)

*.standardHost2[*].app[0].typename = "UdpVideoStreamClient"
*.standardHost2[*].app[0].serverAddress = "Server"
*.standardHost2[*].app[0].serverPort = 1000
*.standardHost2[*].app[0].startTime = uniform(0s, 0.1s)

*.standardHost3[*].app[0].typename = "UdpVideoStreamClient"
*.standardHost3[*].app[0].serverAddress = "Server"
*.standardHost3[*].app[0].serverPort = 1000
*.standardHost3[*].app[0].startTime = uniform(0s, 0.1s)

*.Server.app[0].typename = "UdpVideoStreamServer"
*.Server.app[0].localPort = 1000
*.Server.app[0].sendInterval = 0.001s
*.Server.app[0].packetLen =1400B
*.Server.app[0].videoSize = 1Gb
```

Answer (score 1):

In your NED try to change the line
`configurator: Ipv4FlatNetworkConfigurator {`

into:
`configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {`

Comment: Please do NOT edit the original question with the fix as the question becomes meaningless in that case. If the answer solves your problem, indicate the answer as accepted without changing your original question.